# Proving $ \forall r, s \in \mathbb{R^+} \sqrt {r. s} = \sqrt r . \sqrt s$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-verification, proof-writing

I am new to writing proofs, I have written down a proof for $ \forall r, s \in \mathbb{R^+}  \sqrt {r\cdot s}  = \sqrt r \cdot  \sqrt s$

I know I am a bit messy with my proof, I would love to get some feedback. Also please verify if my proof is good enough. Here is my approach,

Proof -  Let, $\sqrt r = p$ and $\sqrt s = q$ where  $p, q \in \mathbb{R^+}$.

Then,
$\sqrt r \sqrt s  = p\cdot q$ ... (1)

Squaring both the sides we get,
$(\sqrt r \sqrt s)^2  = (p\cdot q)^2$   ...(2)

$(\sqrt r \sqrt s)^2 = (r^{1/2}\cdot s^{1/2})^2$  [as $\sqrt a = a^{1/2}$]

> Lemma 1 - $\forall a, b \in  \mathbb{R} [(a\cdot  b )^2 = a^2\cdot  b^2] $
>
> Proof - By definition of squaring, $ a^2 = a\cdot a$
>
> It follows from the definition that, $(a \cdot b)^2 = (a \cdot b ) (a\cdot b) = a^2\cdot b^2$ $\blacksquare$

From lemma 1,

$(r^{1/2}\cdot s^{1/2})^2 = r^{2 / 2}\cdot  s^{2/2} = r\cdot s$

Therefore,

$(\sqrt r \sqrt s)^2 =  r\cdot s$

From equation 2, we have,

$r\cdot s = (p\cdot q)^2 $  ...(3)

If the equality holds the LHS of the equation must yield the same result as equation 1,

Now from equation 3,

$ \sqrt {r\cdot  s} = \sqrt{(p\cdot q)^2}$

$\sqrt{(p\cdot q)^2} = ((p\cdot q)^2)^{1/2}$ [as $\sqrt a = a^{1/2}$]

Now from the power rule $(a^b)^c = a^{b\cdot c}$, it follows that

$((p\cdot q)^2)^{1/2} = (p\cdot q)^{2/2}= p\cdot q$ .. (4)

From equation (1) and equation (4). As both sides yield the same result, it is true that, $ \forall r, s \in \mathbb{R^+}  \sqrt {r. s}  = \sqrt r \cdot \sqrt s$ $\blacksquare$

I have one concern with this proof, by this same reasoning that I have followed, I can even prove the statement for $\forall r, s \in \mathbb{R^-}$, which is **not true**, so I must be wrong somewhere.

Comment: I didn't read your proof, but regarding the last statement I have this to say: given a *non-negative* real number $x$ ,$\sqrt x$ by definition is the only non-negative real number $y$ such that $y^2=x$. So there's no way the proof would work with negative $r$, since the symbol $\sqrt r$ would be meaningless.

Comment: Tex advice: Use \cdot for the multiplication dot.

Comment: Why are you using the term "Discrete Mathematics" ? (discrete = discontunuous) It bears no relationship with what you are doing.

Comment: @GitGud - That makes sense. Thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: Well, in fact, it is true for all real numbers. But you can not use this proof for negative numbers (if you are tlaking about arithmetical root) because it is undefined

Comment: @JeanMarie - How to prove mathematical arguments is being taught in Discrete Math course that I am taking online, so I thought it is related to Discrete Math. You are correct, edited the text.

Comment: @shuhalo - I will keep that in mind. New to LaTeX.

Comment: @RhitikBhatt It's common for Discrete Mathematics courses to deal with introductory proofs for subjects related to "continuous" mathematics, but this isn't really discrete mathematics.

Comment: Regarding the problem at hand, this is how I would prove it. Firstly I assume that the fact $\forall x\in \mathbb R^+\exists !y\in \mathbb R^+(y^2=x)$ is already proven and that given such $x$, the unique $y$ is denoted by $\sqrt x$. So you want to prove that $\sqrt{rs}$ equals $\sqrt r\sqrt s$. In other words, you want to prove that with $x=rs$, you have $y=\sqrt r\sqrt s$. Well, for this you just need to prove that $(\sqrt r\sqrt s)^2$ equals $rs$. You know that $(\sqrt r\sqrt s)^2=\sqrt r^2\sqrt s^2$ and, by definition of $\sqrt.$, $\sqrt r^2=r\land \sqrt s^2=s$, so $(\sqrt r\sqrt s)^2=rs$.

Comment: Since the purpose of what you are doing is to learn proofs, it should be pointed out that you have implicitly assumed $\sqrt{r} = r^{1/2}$ and $(r^{1/2})^2 = r^{2/2}$.  Both of those are nontrivial, and far more complicated assumptions than the theorem you are trying to prove.  The only assumptions you really need are $\sqrt{r}^2 = r$ and $(a\cdot b)^2 = a^2\cdot b^2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since, as you say, ''you are new to writing proofs'', I think that you want some advice to improve your proof.

The first step is to start with a good definition of the mathematical objects that you are using. In this case we need a definition of $\sqrt{a}$ for $a\in \mathbb{R}^+$. This definition is:

> $1) \qquad \sqrt{a}$ is a **non negative real number**  $x\ge 0$ such that $x^2=a$

The second step is to well define what we want to prove, and in this case it is the identity: $\sqrt{ab}=\sqrt{a}\sqrt{b}$, where ( by the definition $1)$) we have: $\sqrt{a}=x\ge 0$ , $\sqrt{b}=y\ge 0$ and $\sqrt{ab}=z\ge 0$, such that $z^2=ab$, $y^2=b$ and $x^2=a$ (**note that this exclude the possibility that $a,b$ (and $ab$) can be negative numbers**).

Now, for the proof, we can start from the LHS or from the RHS of this identity.

From the LHS:
$$
\sqrt{ab}=z \Rightarrow z^2=ab=x^2y^2
$$
So, using commutativity of the product in $\mathbb{R}$:
$$
z^2=(xy)^2
$$
and, since $xy\ge 0$ we can write
$$
xy=\sqrt{ab}=z 
$$
that is:
$$
\sqrt{a}\sqrt{b}=\sqrt{ab}
$$

Note that we don't need fractional exponents, but only the definition of the square root. in particular we did not use the rule $(a^b)^c=a^{bc}$ that is not valid, in general, for a fractional exponent.

In your proof you  started from the RHS,
I leave to you the writing of the proof in this case.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you.

Comment: It is worth to mention this is based on two-dimensional Euclidean space. There exist another plane where a and b can be negative numbers as well.

Answer (score 2):

Your proof is right. It fails in the case $r=-1, s=-1$ because then the power rule $(a^b)^c = a^{bc}$ doesn't apply: it necessarily applies when everything's positive, but not necessarily otherwise.